# How to make <td> to overlap adjacent <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using the following code to perform colspan operation and I want to eliminate the second  after the colspan but the second  is appearing by stretching the boarder.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
     <td>Should Not Display</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate that `td[colspan="2"]` overlaps the last `td` you can use `position`

example:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

td[colspan="2"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
      <td>Should Not Display</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: I am using this td[colspan="2"]+td {
  display: none;
} as suggested but is it possible to do the same for colspan="3".

Comment: @SampathSam Sure. Use `td[colspan="3"]+td { display: none; }` instead

Answer (score -1):

Just delete `<td>Should Not Display</td>`

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
</body>
```